# Is there any way to use shadowOpacity in react native for android?

Tags: android, react-native

Shadow style works fine for iOS but on Android only elevation works and I can't add style to it? So is there any way to add shadowOpacity, shadowColor, shadowOffset ... etc?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/shadow-props.html#props), those are only available for iOS.
The only way to add shadow on Android is with elevation, like you said.
You can also read about this issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2768) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

If it can help someone today (it's been a while) :

It is possible to give elevation and a shadowColor on android, if you use rgba colors you can add transparency, here I put 0.5 for opacity :

```
  myStuff: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    elevation: 5,
    shadowColor: 'rgba(152, 152, 152, 0.5)',
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Shadow Props](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/shadow-props.html#props) to define shadows on Android now because the issue Vincent referenced was resolved with this [Pull Request](https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit/pull/231).

Comment: As I mentioned on the top only elevation works but you can't really style it the way you want but shadow props works fine on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

As rightly mentioned above

```
elevation
```

is the only supported way of adding shadow.

However, there is a third party plugin that can help you out.

```
https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow
```

> Attribute we support now
>
> opacity: the opacity of shadow

Comment: This is a resource I came across while trying to work on shadows, it allows you to have some control over shadows.I know it's not the best way to solve this issue , so will appreciate any suggestions to improve this issue